# .Net library to save 3D geometry to standard 3D formats

Tags: library, .net, 3d, file-format

I am working on a project where I generate 3D geometry (Triangles, Quads, Lines, Text) and display it in particular colors on a stand-alone windows application using 3D WPF. I want to save this geometry into a standard file format like OBJ, 3DS, VRML to store and reuse this geometry.

Are there any .Net libraries (preferably free) that would allow me to save the 3D geometry to any standard 3d format?

It can be a low-level library, where I manually create the 3D primitives, assign properties, and then save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the answer to this question is probably a simple No. Most libraries in the 3D community revolve around native code (typically written in c/c++). So what you will probably need is to find an unmanaged native library and incorporate that into your .NET project.

If you broaden your search to allow any c/c++ library, you should find some options.

Comment: Thank you, would you suggest any c/c++ library in particular?

Comment: I haven't done 3d work in a long time. I don't remember any of the libraries. But like I said, you should be able to find some libs on Google if you change your search to C or C++.  You could try getting plugged in to the Blender development community or the 3D game development community.  Either join a forum or get on IRC to chat with those folks.  The 3D game dev community is full of people that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ogre 3D community also.